# Examples of convergent evolution?

Tags: language-change, evolution

As an English-speaking student of Yiddish, I was pleasantly surprised to discover that the indefinite article was *an* before vowels and *a* before consonants, just like in English. But as far as I can tell, Yiddish developed this independently from English. That is, both turned the Proto-German **ainaz* ("one") into two separate words, the number one (*eyn* in Yiddish) and an indefinite article which is identical in the two languages.

Are there any other examples of two languages which shared a root, separated, and ended up with nearly identical words much later, despite otherwise diverging considerably?

Comment: Well, there is a famous example of an indigenous australian language in which the word for dog is 'dog', pronounced the same way as in at least some English dialects:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbabaram_language#Word_for_.22dog.22

My guess would be that placing a consonant there would be preferred based on phonetics. Saying 'a orange' is slightly annoying, since you have to put something like a glottal stop in between unless you want to run the two vowels together.

Comment: Actually, the consonant went the other way around--i.e., it used to be both "an cat" and "an apple," and the "n" was lost before consonants. But my question is about two languages experiencing parallel changes, rather than randomly having similar words.

Comment: @Alan: Anschel is specifically asking about languages with a shared root, which rules out Mbabaram, otherwise one of my favourites too of course.

Comment: should we discourage this kind of "examples" questions?

Comment: Ah, well having a "shared root" (it's quite possible that English and Mbabaram do, of course) is not necessary for convergent evolution, but I guess if that's what the poster wants I will be sure not to clutter up the comments.  ;)

Comment: Maybe convergent is the wrong word...I'm thinking of a case of two languages carrying out the same change, with the same result.

Comment: Since convergent evolution is not what you're looking for, perhaps you're just looking for stochastic examples between closely related languages.

Comment: @AlanH.: Mbabaram *dog* and English *dog* [don't have a shared root](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dog#Etymology_2). The Mbabaram word is related to words in other Australian languages like Dyirbal *guda* and Yidiny *gudaga*. The English word comes from [an Old English word meaning "muscle"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dog#Etymology). If the two languages have a common ancestor it must be in Africa at least 70,000 years ago, about 20 times further back than we have evidence of any language at all.

Comment: And then there is the question of what do you consider as "nearly identical"?

Comment: @OtavioMacedo: I guess that's subjective; I meant "so similar as to be surprising."

Comment: @hippietrail: I don't think there's much agreement among linguists about the etymology of *dog*. I can't help but notice that Wiktionary doesn't cite a source, or explain how "muscle" came to mean "hound".

Comment: @anschel: I'd never heard the "muscle" story either but in any case "dog" is a recent innovation just in English and doesn't have a shared root with other IE languages word for dog.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My favorite example is the convergent evolution of *do* support.  In Modern English, auxiliary *do* must be used in questions and negative sentences:

```
(1) John did not kiss Mary
(2) Who did John kiss?
```

[Beninca and Poletto (1998)](http://lear.unive.it/bitstream/10278/444/1/8.1.2.pdf) find that a northern Italian Romance dialect has developed a system of *do* support very similar to the English one (though it applies only to questions).  This pattern is not attested in any world languages other than these two.<sup>1</sup>  I'm unclear on the etymology.  The OED says English *do* comes from the "Aryan [=PIE? –AE] verb stem dhē-, dhō-" which it relates to the second element in the Latin verbs *ab-dĕre* to put away, *con-dĕre* to put together, *dē-dĕre* to lay down, but not to *facere*, the source of the Italian word for *do*.  On the other hand, [Wiktionary](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wiktionary/en/wiki/Appendix%3aProto-Indo-European/d%CA%B0eh%E2%82%81-) traces Engl. *do* and Lat. *facere* to a common root (PIE **d<sup>h</sup>eh<sub>1</sub>-*), but without listing any sources.

---

1: If you know of another example, me and my research would love to hear about it!

Comment: I guess this is what I was looking for--in retrospect it wasn't a very good question, but this is a very good answer.

Comment: Middle Welsh has a construction rather like do-support, though not just in negative and interrogative contexts. Some argue that English acquired the pattern from a Celtic substrate.

Comment: There's no doubt that *do* and *facere* are cognates (from PIE *dheh1-); initial *dh- > f- is a regular change in Latin. (The source of the -c- is something of a problem, but that's a different story.)

Answer (score 2):

From Germanic languages, both High German and English developed the same diphthong au in the words Haus/house and Maus/mouse independently, while Low German keeps the original long u.

English and High German also both diphthongised the long i to ai, e.g., in mein/my where Low German keeps the original long i.

Answer (score 1):

Some examples taken from the Wiktionary appendix on the [Proto-Indo-European roots](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix%3aList_of_Proto-Indo-European_roots):

- **Latin**: *pater*; **Greek**: *patēr*; **PIE root**: **ph₂tḗr* (father)
- **Russian**: пизда (*pizdá*); **Lithuanian**: *pyzdà*; **Latvian**: *pīzda*; **Polish**: *pizda*; **PIE root**: **pisd-eh₂-* (vulva)
- **Umbrian**: *pumpe*; **Welsh**: *pump*; **PIE root**: **pénkʷe* (five)
- **Latvian**: *spenis*; **Old Prussian**: *spenis*; **PIE root**: **psten-* (breast)
- **Greek**: τρέμω (*trémō*); **Latin**: tremō; **PIE root**: **ter-* (to shake, tremble)
- **Illyrian**: tri-; **Sanskrit**; **Welsh**: tri; **Sanskrit**: tri; **Hittite**: θri; **Albanian**: tre/tri. **PIE root**: **tréyes, tri- [prefix]* (three)
- **Old Irish**: dia; **Portuguese**: dia; **PIE root**: **déi-no-* (day)

And the list goes on and on.

Comment: Aren't these examples of shared ancestry rather than convergent evolution?

Comment: That's what the OP wants: "examples of two languages which shared a root, separated, and ended up with nearly identical words much later"

Comment: Of course now I have to vote up your answer! (-:

Comment: Note that the Russian word "пизда" is considered vulgar today, whereas "vulva" is not. In fact, in colloquial usage it is much closer to the English "pussy".

Comment: Most of these example did not significantly "separate" and then converge: they remained pretty much the same throughout their history. Even the Umbrian and Welsh case, where they independently developed from "kwenkwe" does not show this diverging and then reconvergence.

Comment: In many of these examples, the common ancestor was not PIE, but a more recent proto-language (Proto-Balto-Slavic, Proto-Baltic etc), hence some of them are not convergences, but inherited similarities.

Answer (score 1):

I saw a video a while back by YouTuber Artifexian (https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=PBz-JT00MZs) which presents evidence that many languages seem to evolve some similar features based on geography. The most detailed example he mentions in the video is that ejective consonants, where the sound is produced only by the throat and mouth without extra air from the lungs, tend to appear in languages native to high-altitude regions where it might be helpful not to lose excess moisture by breathing into the consonant sounds. Although he doesn't mention this directly in the video, two of the areas where ejectives are common are in the Andes range and the Rockies, and it is commonly believed that native American languages all evolved from the languages spoken by the first Siberians to cross the Bering land bridge. So although the languages of the Andes are distant "cousins" to those of the Rockies, there is a sizable gap between the areas and they probably developed ejectives independently.

Answer (score -2):

Enlish *strange* and Russian *stranno*, with the same meaning; English *stranger* and Russian *strannik*, with the same meaning. But English and Russian words derived from different and unrelated roots.